# Eclipse - java source file organization

Tags: java, eclipse, project

this is a source file organization question - 
I used to create separate Eclipse Projects for solutions to example problems I solved ( eg: the first one is for Exercise 1.1.2 ). Each project has a single java file with a main() function that does the work/testing. So as I keep adding new solutions the number of projects grows which is pretty unwieldy. And each project has just one java file, so there must be a better way to organize these.

What are some good ways/best practices to consolidate all these into a single project?

( Just stick the files together/ have a single main method, etc.. )

[image]

Comment: This question is too general. What do all these projects do, and why did you make separate projects in the first place instead of one or two projects with several files? Are you wanting to run multiple examples independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do. Create one project in Eclipse called "Exercises". The project should have one `src` folder and one `test` folder. Group your code into packages as suggested in another answer; `com.exercises.chapterone`, there either create a java class for each exercise, or one large class for each chapter with separate methods for each exercise.

Then create JUnit tests that mirror your code and run each class/method to verify that it works. You don't need a main class to run code. This will keep your workspace small and tidy and it will help you to learn how to unit test your code. This is a very important thing to learn, so the sooner you start to do it, the better.

So, something like this

Exercices

- src

  - com.exercise.chapterone

    - Exercise1.java

      - oneOneOne(...)
      - oneOneTwo(...)
    - Exercise2.java
- test

  - com.exercise.chapterone

    - TestExercise1.java

      - TestOneOneOne(...)
      - TestOneOneTwo(...)
    - TestExercise2.java

Answer (score 0):

A place to start would to put them in one project and group them logically in packages.

E.g. you can put all 1.1 exercises in a package named `com.exercises.oneone`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can group your exercises using packages, one exercise per package. 
And then with each exercise, provide one entrance method for test, instead of a main function. And at last, you can run test using some testing libs such as junit, or you can even write a single main function to test all your exercises. 
If you require independence between exercises, with junit, you can run each test case independently. While using single main function, you can pass some args into the main and determine which exercise to run.
Hope this will help you.